# map is adding the previous values also

Tags: apex, map

My VF Page

```
<apex:inputFile id="atchmntA" value="{!contentFile}" filename="{!nameFile}" title="Please select the CSV file to upload" onchange="verifyAttachmentSize(this)"/>
<apex:commandButton action="{!createFLS}" value="Create FLS" id="theButton" style="width:70px;" />
```

My Apex Class is

```
private Map<String, FieldPermissions> field_FLS_Map ;

//My Constructor
public FLSController()  {
   field_FLS_Map = new Map<String, FieldPermissions>(); 
}

 Public pagereference createFLS(){
//some code
createSOQL(fls.sObjectName, field_API_object, fls.profileName, fls.access) ;
}


private void createSOQL(String objName, String fieldAPIName, String profileName, String access){

        FieldPermissions newFls = new FieldPermissions();
        if(access!='' && access!='N/A') {    // if access has to be changed 

            String flsKey = fieldAPIName +''+profilePermissionSetMap.get(profileName);
            if(profilePermissionSetMap.get(profileName) ==null){
         //   System.debug( 'profileName: ' + profileName);
            }
            System.debug('****** flsKey : ' + flsKey + '  ** Already Exists: ' + existingFLS.containskey(flsKey) ); 
            if(!existingFLS.containskey(flsKey)){
                newFls.SObjectType = objName;
                newFls.Field = fieldAPIName;
                newFls.parentid  = profilePermissionSetMap.get(profileName);
            } else {
                newFls = existingFLS.get(flsKey);
            }

            if(access== 'None'){    
                newFls.PermissionsRead = false ; 
                newFls.PermissionsEdit = false;
            } else if(access == 'Read'){    
                newFls.PermissionsRead = true ; 
                newFls.PermissionsEdit = false;
            } else if(access == 'Edit'){
                newFls.PermissionsRead = true ; 
                newFls.PermissionsEdit = true;
            } 
            system.debug('2----'+flsKey +'111'+newFLS);
            field_FLS_Map.put(flsKey, newFLS);
            system.debug('1---'+field_FLS_Map.size() );
        }
    }
```

when i try to upload the file for second time the field_FLS_Map is containing the previous values as well. How can i remove them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable is containing the old values because, it is initialized only once in `constructor` and thereafter, values will be kept on adding.

So to avoid that, you can initialize your `map` from a `action method` which is getting called from `commandButton`. Assuming that your `createSOQL` method is called in a loop, if not, then `map` would always contain 1 element. So, in your case, you can do that in `createFLS` method.

So your `createFLS` would look like

```
Public pagereference createFLS(){
    field_FLS_Map = new Map<String, FieldPermissions>(); 
    //some code
    createSOQL(fls.sObjectName, field_API_object, fls.profileName, fls.access) ;
}
```

Comment: I tried that before but it was taking only the last record and it size here was 1.

Comment: Yes, its size would be always 1 as you are adding elements to the map only once. Are you calling `createSOQL` method in for loop, if yes, then move this code `field_FLS_Map = new Map<String, FieldPermissions>();` from `createSOQL` to `createFLS`

Comment: Perfect. It worked. To my anxiety as said by Pranay can I declare this variable as atatic or transient?

Comment: Great !! No need to make that variable as static or transient

Comment: But as a best practice i guess we have to make them as transient to avoid having view state error wright? it would be helpful if you can help me in this as well

Comment: Yes, you should mark those variables as transient which you think should not be saved in view state. You can refer [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_transient.htm) link to learn more on this concept. My comment was solely based on the current question i.e. you don't have to mark that variable as static or transient to get that working.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see `field_FLS_Map` is variable defined at controller level. Its not defined as static or transient thus it will part of View State.

field_FLS_Map as being part of ViewState will maintain values between multiple client-server communication/calls/request.

Visualforce is stateful, you have to re-initialize the variable each time you make `createSOQL` call.

`field_FLS_Map = new Map<String, FieldPermissions>();`

Comment: I tried that before but it was taking only the last record and it size here was 1. Any other suggestions